# Volume of a sphere using python3-scipy.integrate

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I'm trying to catch up on using python for numerical problems after not using it for quite some time. I am working towards solving a toy problem of calculating the volume of a fairly arbitrary shape (parametrically specified). So far to do this I have a base class as follows:

```
class BaseWithRange():
    def __init__(self):
        self._x_range = None

    @property
    def x_range_min(self):
        return self.x_range[0]

    @property
    def x_range_max(self):
        return self.x_range[1]

    @property
    def x_range(self):
        if self._x_range is None:
            raise NotImplementedError("You need to set the x range value")
        return self._x_range

    @x_range.setter
    def x_range(self, range):
        self._x_range = range

    def _check_in_x_range(self, x):
        errString = f"'x' is out of range of ({self.x_range_min}, {self.x_range_max}) at {x}"
        if hasattr(x, "__iter__") and not isinstance(x, str):
            if (x < self.x_range_min).any() or (x > self.x_range_max).any():
                raise ValueError(errString)
        else:
            if x < self.x_range_min or x > self.x_range_max:
                raise ValueError(errString)

    def _val(self, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def val(self, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError()


class BaseWithTwoRanges(BaseWithRange):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._y_range = None

    @property
    def y_range_min(self):
        return self.y_range[0]

    @property
    def y_range_max(self):
        return self.y_range[1]

    @property
    def y_range(self):
        if self._y_range is None:
            raise NotImplementedError("You need to set the y range value")
        return self._y_range

    @y_range.setter
    def y_range(self, range):
        self._y_range = range

    def _check_in_y_range(self, y):
        errString = f"'y' is out of range of ({self.y_range_min}, {self.y_range_max}) at {y}"
        if hasattr(y, "__iter__") and not isinstance(y, str):
            if (y < self.y_range_min).any() or (y > self.y_range_max).any():
                raise ValueError(errString)
        else:
            if y < self.y_range_min or y > self.y_range_max:
                raise ValueError(errString)

class SolidBase(BaseWithTwoRanges):
    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
    @property
    def volume(self):
        volume, error = integrate.tplquad(self._val, self.x_range_min, self.x_range_max, self.y_lower_of_x, self.y_upper_of_x, self.z_lower_of_xy, self.z_upper_of_xy)
        print("Error: ", error)
        return volume

    def _val(self, z, y, x, *args): 
        try:
            self._check_in_x_range(x)
            self._check_in_y_range(y)
            return self.val(z, y, x, *args)
        except:
            t, v, tb = sys.exc_info()
            errorString = "Failed when called with these variables: \n y    = {0}\n x    = {1}\n args = {2}".format(y, x, args)

            raise t("{0}\n{1}".format(v, errorString))

    def val(self, z, y, x, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def y_lower_of_x(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def y_upper_of_x(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def z_lower_of_xy(self, x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def z_upper_of_xy(self, x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

... and for a sphere I have implemented the following:

```
class Sphere(SolidBase):
    def __init__(self, radius, center = [0,0,0]):
        super().__init__()
        self.radius = radius
        self.center = center
        self.x_range = [center[0], center[0] + radius]
        self.y_range = [center[1], center[1] + radius]

    def val(self, z, y, x):
        a = self.center[0]
        b = self.center[1]
        c = self.center[2]
        return c + sqrt(self.radius**2 - (x - a)**2 - (y - b)**2)

    def y_lower_of_x(self, x):
        return 0

    def y_upper_of_x(self, x):
        a = self.center[0]
        b = self.center[1]
        return b + sqrt(self.radius**2 - (x - a)**2)

    def z_lower_of_xy(self, x, y):
        return 0

    def z_upper_of_xy(self, x, y):
        a = self.center[0]
        b = self.center[1]
        c = self.center[2]
        return c + sqrt(self.radius**2 - (x - a)**2 - (y - b)**2)
```

The problem is that the volume result for a sphere with radius 2 gives a result for a quarter hemisphere of 6.28, which is just not right. In other words:

```
In [14]: sphere = sh.Sphere(2)

In [15]: sphere.volume
Error:  8.845676088407289e-08
Out[15]: 6.283185307096017
```

... rather than the expected (4/3*pi*2**3) / 8 = 4.1887902047863905.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Edit: Added more code are added missing words.

Comment: There are parts invisible to us that we may need, e.g., Class BaseWithTwoRanges, which I imagine defines x_range_min etc.

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I've added the missing bits, but they really don't participate in the calculation.

Comment: The answer is here: https://scipython.com/book/chapter-8-scipy/examples/the-volume-of-the-unit-square/, but I don't understand why the "func" param is required to just return the radius.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the approximate volume of arbitrary shapes, numerical quadrature might not help you much. The problem is that almost all quadrature methods assume reasonable smoothness of the function you're trying to integrate (e.g., polynomials of a certain degree). The characteristic function of a domain is not smooth at all.

A better approach is to approximate your domain with simplices and then add their volumes. Python tools that can help you with the task are

- [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh) (project of mine)
- [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh) (another project of mine)

Search for *mesh generation* and you'll find more.